# Symlinked gitconfig resolves include relative to symlink

Tags: symlink, git

I added a gitconfig to my dotfiles. To keep things tidy, a symlink at `~/.gitconfig` points to the real file, which lives elsewhere.

I want to have a section like:

```
[include]
    path = other-file.txt
```

in my gitconfig. But this doesn't work because it tries to include `~/other-file.txt` (relative to symlink) which doesn't exist. Instead I have to use:

```
[include]
    path = /absolute/path/to/other-file.txt
```

But if I ever move my dotfiles directory, now this include will break. Is there a way to make the relative path work?

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't a way to get Git to resolve symlinks before computing a relative path.  The documentation specifically says that it's relative to the file being loaded, which is `~/.gitconfig`.

However, Git supports multiple per-user files.  There's `$HOME/.gitconfig` and `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config`.  In the latter case, if `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is not set, it defaults to `~/.config`.  As a result, you can store your Git configuration in `~/.config/git/config` and then also have `~/.config/git/other-file.txt`, which should work correctly.